# How are values cast when assigning to a Boolean field in Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, boolean

**Short version of my question**

In Rails ActiveRecord, if I have a Boolean field and I assign it something like "`abc`" or `2`, then it gets immediately cast to `false`.  The value `1` is cast to `true`, and `nil` remains as `nil`.  Why is this the case?  Where can I find Rails documentation (or Ruby documentation) that explains this behavior?

**Long version of my question**

I am having difficulty understanding how Rails handles attempts to assign values to a `Boolean` field in a Rails model.  For example, let's say I have a `Website` model that has a `String` field called `:domain` and a `Boolean` field called `:can_ssl`.

My migration looks like this:

```
class CreateWebsites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :websites do |t|
      t.string :domain
      t.boolean :can_ssl, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my model file, I add some validation rules, so it looks like this:

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :domain, :presence => true
  validates :can_ssl, :inclusion =>  { :in => [true, false] }
end
```

Simple enough.  Based on what I've done, I'm **expecting** that `:can_ssl` can only be set to the values `true` or `false`, and nothing else.  Anything else would result in `valid?` being `false`.

But once I start playing around in the console, I notice that, as early as the actual assignment statement, the value I provide is being recast to `true` or `false` (or `nil`).  What are the rules governing how a value gets cast as a `Boolean`?

Examples from the console:

```
w = Website.new
w.domain = 'stackoverflow.com'
w.can_ssl = true
w.can_ssl    # => true
w.valid?     # => true

w.can_ssl = nil
w.can_ssl    # => nil
w.valid?     # => false (so far so good)

w.can_ssl = 'abc'
w.can_ssl    # => false (How did 'abc' become the value false?)
w.valid?     # => true

w.can_ssl = 1
w.can_ssl    # => true (I guess it makes sense that 1 casts to true)
w.valid?     # => true

w.can_ssl = 2
w.can_ssl    # => false (But anything other than 1 casts to false?)
w.valid?     # => true
```

So, based on what I've done so far, I *think* I can conclude the following:

- When assigning the value `1` or `true` to a `Boolean` field, the value will immediately get cast as `true` and then assigned.
- When assigning `nil` to a `Boolean` field, the field is actually assigned `nil`.
- When assigning anything else (such as a `String` or any number that is not `1`), then the value will immediately get cast as `false`.

Am I understanding that correctly?  Am I missing anything?

I'm having difficulty finding documentation the `Boolean` field type in Rails which can give me clarification on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done in the bowels of ActiveRecord: specifically with

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean
```

at least in my version of rails (it may be somewhere slightly different in more recent versions).

Here's the source in my version

```
    # File activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb, line 144
    144:         def value_to_boolean(value)
    145:           if value.is_a?(String) && value.blank?
    146:             nil
    147:           else
    148:             TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
    149:           end
    150:         end
```

where TRUE_VALUES is defined as

```
#activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:10:      
TRUE_VALUES = [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE'].to_set
```

1, 0, "f" and "t" are there because of popular DBMS's like MySql & PostgreSql, which store bools as 0/1 and "f"/"t" respectively.

It's worth noting the difference between this and what passes an "if" test in Ruby/Rails, ie values that are "truthy" or "falsy" ("falsy" values will fail an if test, "truthy" values will pass it).

In Ruby, `nil` and `false` are "falsy" and literally **anything** else (including 0, empty arrays, empty strings, empty hashes etc) is "truthy".  So, there's a massive disparity between what is deemed truthy/falsy in ruby and what is saved as true/false to a boolean database column.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of boolean columns changed with two commits:

- [e01a46f](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e01a46f1f0e21d9018906a6a8dcfdae2d92f32ae) (2014-10-17)
- [a502703](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a502703c3d2151d4d3b421b29fefdac5ad05df61) (2015-01-04).

The new rule is very simple. See the code below:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Type
    class Boolean < Value # :nodoc:
      def type
    :boolean
      end

      private

      def cast_value(value)
    if value == ''
      nil
    else
      !ConnectionAdapters::Column::FALSE_VALUES.include?(value)
    end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The constant `ConnectionAdapters::Column::FALSE_VALUES` is defined as follows:

```
[false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE', 'off', 'OFF'].to_set
```

If a value is not an empty string and is not among them, it will be cast to `true`.

This change will become effective on the Rails 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ruby thing rather than a Rails thing. Boolean is "truthy". There's a pretty useful article on it here. https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362

Comment: This isn't what he was asking: he was asking "why does 'abc' get saved as "false" to a boolean column".  "abc" is truthy in ruby, which seems like a contradiction.