# To validate or not to validate boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there any benefit in having validations for boolean fields of models?

I had a validation for ensuring the presence of a boolean field

```
validates :boolean_attribute, presence: true
```

It failed when boolean_attribute was false. I googled around and found these SO questions relating to the issue.

[Rails database defaults and model validation for Boolean fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506575/rails-database-defaults-and-model-validation-for-boolean-fields)
[Rails validates_presence not validating on Boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002946/rails-validates-presense-not-validating-on-boolean)

Then added this validation instead

```
 validates :field, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
```

This made me think. Do I need any validations for boolean fields at all? Its value will always be true or false or nil right? Even if someone maliciously try to change it to say, a number, wouldn't the type take care of it? Or is there some safety the above inclusion validation provides?

Comment: yeah, I usually don't bother. If the field is mandatory - you can use the inclusion-in trick above, and to be sure put `null: false` on the column

Comment: If you need the value to be `true` or `false` but not `nil` then you want to use the validation. If `true`, `false`, and `nil` are all okay, you don't need the validation. Which of those is correct for you depends entirely on your use case.

Comment: @Jordan: I'm cool with nil as long as ruby validates it to false and there are no scenarios that might break the system. Are there any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whether or not you should validate a boolean attribute for inclusion in `[ true, false ]` depends entirely on your use case.

You've correctly identified that, in the absence of validation of other code, a boolean field in Rails will always be (after type coercion) `true`, `false`, or `nil`. Rails won't coerce `nil` to `false`. If you set a model's boolean attribute to `nil` and save it, the attribute will be `nil`, not `false`, when you fetch the it from the database later.

You can think of `nil` as a "third state" for a boolean field. Consider a simple survey app that lets users save an unfinished survey to complete later. Suppose a user saves an incomplete survey with the question "Do you eat meat?" unanswered. You don't want to store `false` in the database because that would indicate that the user answered "no." When the user comes back to finish the survey you want that question to still be unanswered, so you want to store `nil` in the database.

In cases like the above, it's appropriate (and necessary) *not* to validate for inclusion in `[ true, false ]`.

However, as a rule of thumb I would say that in all other cases—i.e. in any case where you don't have a specific *need* for `nil` values—you should validate boolean fields for inclusion in `[ true, false ]`.

Of course, if you *do* allow `nil` you'll need to be careful because, as you know, `nil` is a *falsey* value in Ruby. You'll have to explicitly check for "nilness" in places where you might otherwise rely on a value's truthiness or falsiness. That is, instead of this:

```
if !is_meat_eater
  unanswered_questions << :is_meat_eater
end
```

...which will not behave as intended if `is_meat_eater` is `false`, you'll need to explicitly check for `nil`:

```
if is_meat_eater.nil?
  unanswered_questions << :is_meat_eater
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to validate a `boolean` field, **if it's not true it's false**.

Just [set a "default" in your db](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) so that the bool is always going to have a certain value no matter what:

```
#db/migrate/add_boolean_column_______.rb
class AddBooleanColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_table :table do |t|
         t.boolean :field, default: false
      end
   end
end
```

This way, I wouldn't even include any validations. The system will ensure you're either setting it as true or false - which is up to you as the developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want real type validation, I'd say check out the [`validates_type`](https://github.com/yez/validates_type) gem. It will conduct validation on your attribute **before** type coercion. Type coercion can have some unexpected behaviour, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22375231/5129208) shows how only a certain set of values is "truthy".

If you accept a `Boolean` to be `nil`, that's not really a `Boolean` right? That's either `true`, `false` or a third value, `nil`.